# How can I get the min value in an array above a certain number?

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
[5229561]=> 8
[5229582]=> 9
[5229583]=> 10
[5229584]=> 11
```

etc

How can I get the minimum value greater than/equal to 10?

So, it this example, it would give me 5229583. I know about the min() function, but I'm not sure how to get a value greater than 10.

Comment: Yes, it is guaranteed to be unique

Comment: Because of it doesn't not exist a specific function, I think that the fastest method is a linear search (a simple for).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to evaluate the array for this, a number of methods you can use:

for simplicity (and not trying to be fancy) i'll show you the easiest way to learn to do this in PHP.

```
$input_array = array('5229561' => 8,
                     '5229582' => 9,
                     '5229583' => 10,
                     '5229584' => 11);

foreach ($input_array as $key => $value) {
    if($value >= 10) {
        $output[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

$output will be:

```
array (
      '5229583' => 10,
      '5229584' => 11
      )
```

hope that helps

EDIT Addition: (Due to RiaD post below) another simple method to do this.

```
function greaterTen($var) {
    return ($var >= 10);
}

$output = array_filter($input_array,"greaterTen");
```

and even (as of php5.3):

```
$output = array_filter($input_array,function ($var) {
    return ($var >= 10);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If array is sorted and keys are consecutive(e.g 100,101,102 no 78,5,13) you may use binary search.

Overwise you can't do it more quickly than linear search.

Code with O(1) additional memory usage:

```
$curbest=null;
foreach($data as $k => $v){
    if($v>=10 && (is_null($curbest) || $v<$data[$curbest]))
        $curbest=$k;
}
```

Comment: @sharpner: only one additional variable. O(n) is time complexity, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably want to just sort the array (use `ksort` if you need the keys to stay the same) and then iterate until you find >= the minimum value.

Like so:

```
function findMinValueAbove($array, $min)
{
    sort($array);
    foreach ($array as $v) if ($v >= $min) return $v;
}
```

Comment: It's slower that basic linear search. Besides, sort return bool and you try to foreach it.

Comment: Actually, I just did test rounds between my function and a basic linear search. My function is about 50x faster. Unless I'm doing my testing wrong, which is possible (I just got off an overnight shift ;)).